# Background setting isn't applied to entire sidebar height

Tags: customization, css

I am working on [this WP website](http://www.kensingtonmn.com/wordpress/churches-and-schools/) and can't for the life of me get the entire height of the sidebar to take the background setting.

The theme is a child of TwentyFourteen. Through FireFox's Inspect Element I can see my background-color setting on the #secondary div, which is the main container for the side nav area, but I can't figure out why it's not coloring the entire height of the page, nor how to get it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the WordPress support forums, my question was answered with this code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1008px) {
.site:before { background-color: #ff0000; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the sidebar just isn't tall enough on pages with a lot of content.  You're seeing the black background of the `.site::before` selector.  Around line 639 in style.css change the background color to `#3c5680`.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I tried adding `.site::before { background-color: #3C5680; }` to my style.css file, but that didn't affect it. I also tried adding `!important` to it, too.

Comment: Did you find the `.site::before` selector in your stylesheet and change it?